# Ubuntu 18.04 performance issue playing high quality videos

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, vlc, gpu-driver, totem

I have a clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04 in my Lenovo Thinkpad T510 with Intel i915 graphic card. Playing videos 1080p with both VLC and Totem has severe performance issues. I have tried the fixes suggested in [Video playback performance issue Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029205/video-playback-performance-issue-ubuntu-18-04), but none of them worked for me.

[Bug #1767468](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nux/+bug/1767468)
seems to be related but it does not apply in my case since I have installed Ubuntu from scratch, I did not upgrade from Ubuntu 17.04.

```
$ sudo lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 && sudo lshw -c display
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [17aa:215a]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
  *-display                 
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 2
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       versión: 02
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuración: driver=i915 latency=0
       recursos: irq:25 memoria:f2000000-f23fffff memoria:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8) memoria:c0000-dffff
```

[Bug #1752938](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1752938) is also similar but the packages `libgle-mesa0` and `libglx-mesa0` are already installed in my case.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

`vainfo` output:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.1 (libva 2.1.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile - 2.1.0
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

Comment: Have you tried with a lighter desktop environment? The Ubuntu community flavours Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE and Xubuntu have ligther desktop environments than standard Ubuntu, which makes it easier to play video. [Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389).

Comment: Does mplayer from the command line make it a bit more usable?

Comment: I had a Debian system (with gnome) in the same machine and I could reproduce videos without any problems, Ubuntu seems to have an issue with Intel drivers.

Comment: See my question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot, updates 6 & 7, for things that might be helpful. Report back.

Comment: Can you check with `vainfo` (maybe need to install it) if the codec of the video is supported in hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with VLC 3.0.2 installed using the repository package.

I have compiled VLC 4.0 from source and the issue dissapeared. I could also reproduce high quality videos with MPlayer (sudo apt-get install mpv).

Totem is unable to reproduce 1080p videos, it shows a green screen with audio and subtitles only.

Comment: Regarding the green screen, it might be the same issue as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer-vaapi/+bug/1784242 : a workaround is to remove the gstreamer1.0-vaapi package.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this command,

```
sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```

I faced same problem with videos displayed in distorted manner. After this the video displayed is now with better quality.

[image: Screenshot of earlier how it displayed:] 
[image: Screenshot of later how it displayed:]

Comment: Solved my problem on `HP TouchSmart tm2`, thank you